# MySQL select where $id

Tags: php, sql, get

I have a website with this code snippet:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db('news');
$id_article = $_GET['newsid'];
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id="$id_article"');
{
    echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='.$query['id'].'">'.$query['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
    echo $query['full_content'].'<br / >';
    echo date('D-M-Y', $query['date']).'<br / >';
    echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
    echo '</div>'; 
}
?>
```

The `$id_article` gets the id from an previous request. The `$id_article` works, but the `$query` doesn't. `$query['***']` still blank space. I don't know why. Please help me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get your query result. Use like below:

```
<?php
   mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
   mysql_select_db('news');
   $id_article = intval($_GET['newsid']);
   $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=' . $id_article);

   if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
   {
       $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

       echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
       echo $row['full_content'].'<br / >';
       echo date('D-M-Y', $row['date']).'<br / >';
       echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
       echo '</div>';
   } 
?>
```

Tip: use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql_ functions! Mysql_ functions are deprecated / not supported in new php versions!

Further, sanatize your input before passing to your query!

Comment: What's the matter with the input?

Comment: If you use input from GET or POST, they can contains dangerous content. That's why it's better to clean up, for example via mysql_real_escape_string (better: mysqli_real_escape_string). If you only expect a number, you can use intval (see my example code)

Comment: Can you change the code with mysqli functions please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['id']. " - ". $row['date'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Use as below :

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=' . $id_article);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if(count($row)>0)
{
     echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='.$query['id'].'">'.$row['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
     echo $row['full_content'].'<br / >';
     echo date('D-M-Y', $row['date']).'<br / >';
     echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
     echo '</div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your this code

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id="$id_article"');
{
    echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='.$query['id'].'">'.$query['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
    echo $query['full_content'].'<br / >';
    echo date('D-M-Y', $query['date']).'<br / >';
    echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = $id_article";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
{
    echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='.$result['id'].'">'.$result['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
    echo $result['full_content'].'<br / >';
    echo date('D-M-Y', $result['date']).'<br / >';
    echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors in your code
mysql_query has been depreciated
Use the following code 
and ckeck for the errors

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
$conn = mysql_select_db('news');
$id_article = $_GET['newsid'];
if($query = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$id_article"))){ 
echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid=' . $query['id'] . '">' . $query['subject'] . '</a></h1><br />';
echo $query['full_content'] . '<br / >';
echo date('D-M-Y', $query['date']) . '<br / >';
echo 'Posted by ' . $id_article;
echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
$id_article = $_GET['newsid'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$id_article'";
$query1=mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call a function to get the row returned by the query. You are trying to access the $query instead of the row. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
  mysql_select_db('news');
  $id_article = $_GET['newsid'];
  $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id="$id_article"');

  if ($query) {    
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
    echo '<div class="item"><h1><a href="read-news.php?newsid='. $row['id'].'">'. $row['subject'].'</a></h1><br />';
    echo $row['full_content'].'<br / >';
    echo date('D-M-Y', $row['date']).'<br / >';
    echo 'Posted by '.$id_article;
    echo '</div>'; 
  } else {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
  }
?>
```

You can also take a look at the mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row() functions.